# PHP Using characters from a word to output corresponding paragraphs in correct order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, character

I collect a form field string entry eg. `$Name`
I wish to count the characters in that word, then for each character in that word show some text information relating to each character in a new section. eg if they type `Max` I then have a paragraph of text about `m`, a paragraph about `a` and one about `x`.

So far I use these:

```
$Letters = (str_split($Name));
<?php foreach ($Letters as $value) {
echo "value <br>";
} ?> // shows each letter 

<?php echo mb_strlen ($Name) ?> // prints number of characters in entry 

<?php if (mb_strlen ($Name) > 2): ?> 
*code to make additional text section if $Name has more than eg 2 characters 
<?php endif; ?> //new text section created for eg third letter

<?php echo $Name[2]; ?> // prints third letter of name in the newly created 
//section in this case

<?php echo strpos($Name, "a")?> // will tell me "a" appears in second 
//place in example "Max"
```

But what is an efficient approach to call the relevant text block for each letter of `$Name` and place it in the correct order (assuming these text blocks are written in the same code file)? I don't want to `echo` the above snippet results in the output as currently happens I just want to use those results to help output only the corresponding paragraphs in the correct order. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you'd want something like this?

```
<?php
$texts = [
    'a' => 'text about a',
    'b' => 'text about b',
    // etc
];

$name = 'something';

// Loop over all letters.
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($name); $i++) {
    $letter = mb_substr($name, $i, 1); // Get current letter.
    $text_for_letter = $texts[$letter] ?? null; // Get the text for this letter from the array of texts.

    if ($text_for_letter) {
        echo 'Text for letter ' . $letter . ' is: ' . $text_for_letter;
    }
}
```

Some background info about what's happening:

We're using `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()` and `mb_substr()` instead of `str_split()` because these cover the use of UTF-8 characters. `strlen()` and `str_split()` would break when certain UTF-8 characters are used as input, because those characters could be made up of multiple bytes (e.g. characters from certain foreign alphabets), which aren't interpreted well by non-multibyte-ready functions and functions like `strlen()` might think that a single character is actually two characters.

Here I am assuming that you are working with UTF-8 input. If you are certain that you are not, you might not need mb_* functions.

Comment: Could you please also add explanation why are you using multi-byte functions and why is the loop better than splitting the string into single letters like the OP has done?

Comment: @minitauros This is exactly the sort of approach I was looking for and not something I was yet familiar with so thank you for the full and clear code explanations, the output is much better than what I could get before.

Comment: Perhaps someone could explain how the '??' operator works in this case as I have not seen it before and in the line above that, what the '1' represents is it 'True'?

Comment: ?? is the so called null coalesce operator (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary). It is basically a shorthand for "if isset then that value, else x", e.g. `$a = $b ?? null` = `$a = isset($b) ? $b : null` = `if (isset($b)) { $a = $b; } else { $a = null; }`

Comment: If you want to know what the 1 represents I suggest you look up the function's documentation :).